# How to javascript if(variable condition [object String])

Tags: javascript, variables, if-statement, conditional-statements

//`i want condition using Object String.(Sorry, English little)`

'EX)'

```
var info1 = [
   {orderNum : 001 , state : use , check : O }
   {orderNum : 002 , state : use , check : 1}
   {orderNum : 003 , state : disuse , check : 0}
];
var info2 = [
   {orderNum : 001 , state : use , check : O }
   {orderNum : 002 , state : use , check : 1}
   {orderNum : 003 , state : use , check : 0}
   {orderNum : 004 , state : disuse , check : 0}

];

 var condition = '( info1[i].'+inputText+' == info2[j].'+inputText')';

 console.log(condition)
```

`***result**** ==> 
    (info1[i].orderNum == info1[j].orderNum) && (info1[i].state == info1[j].state);`

`--------------------------------------------------------------------------------`

```
var equalInfo1 = [];
var equalInfo2 = [];
var differInfo1 = [];
var differInfo2 = [];

for(var i=0: i < info1.length; i++{
 for(var j=0; j< info2.length; j++{

   if(condition){ 
  //  condition =>
  // (info1[i].orderNum == info1[j].orderNum) && (info1[i].state == 
  //  info1[j].state)

     equalInfo1.push(info1[i]);
     equalInfo2.push(info2[j]
   }else{
      differInfo1.push[info1[i];
      equalInfo2.push(info2[j];
   }
 }
}

equalInfo1 => [{orderNum : 1 ...}, {orderNum : 2 ...}]
equalInfo2 => [{orderNum : 1 ...}, {orderNum : 2 ...}]
differInfo1 => [{orderNum : 3 ...}]
differInfo2 => [{orderNum : 4 ...}]

//`i want condition using Object String.(Sorry, English little)`
```

//`but, now logic ==> [variable condition = object String.....] = [Incorrect results]` //`but, now logic ==> [variable condition = object String.....] = [Incorrect results]`

`i want`

```
if(variable condition) {

}else{

}
```

//`but, now logic ==> [variable condition = object String.....] = [Incorrect results]`

//Thank you.`

Answer (score 0):

Okay I am going to take a crack at this one. I am assuming a lot here, but I think your problem stems from trying to access an object using a variable.

Your objects are not properly formed. The `OrderNum` values starting with 0 are probably not what you want since JavaScript will treat numbers starting with 0 as base 8 - I converted them to strings for you. Also `state` values need to be strings as well and I added commas after each object to make it valid.

You can access the values of `info1` and `info2` using the `[ ]` operator with a string variable like so

```js
var info1 = [
   {orderNum : "001" , state : "use" , check : 0 },
   {orderNum : "002" , state : "use" , check : 1},
   {orderNum : "003" , state : "disuse" , check : 0}
];

var info2 = [
   {orderNum : "001" , state : "use" , check : 0 },
   {orderNum : "002" , state : "use" , check : 1},
   {orderNum : "003" , state : "use" , check : 0},
   {orderNum : "004" , state : "disuse" , check : 0}
];

var orderNum = "orderNum";
var state = "state";

var info1OrderNum = info1[0][orderNum];
var info2OrderNum = info2[0][orderNum];

var info1State = info1[0][state];
var info2State = info2[0][state];

if(info1OrderNum === info2OrderNum && info1State === info2State){
  console.log("we match!");
}
else{
  console.log("we DO NOT match");
}
```